# Change the style and background color of Widget Window in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

[image]

```
def color_picker(self):
    color = QtGui.QColorDialog.getColor()
    self.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s}" % color.name())
    global selectedcolor
    selectedcolor=color.name()
    print(selectedcolor)
    global RGBcolorfromcolorpicker
    RGBcolorfromcolorpicker=selectedcolor.lstrip('#')

    #This line doesn't work.
    self.QColorDialog.setStyleSheet('QTabBar::tab{background-color: red;}')

    self.send_rgb_color()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just using a static method you can use an object of the class, in this case I have created a class that already implements the functionality of changing the color:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class ColorDialog(QtGui.QColorDialog):
    def __init__(self, initial=QtGui.QColor(), parent=None):
        super(ColorDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setOption(QtGui.QColorDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        self.currentColorChanged.connect(self.onCurrentColorChanged)
        self.onCurrentColorChanged(self.currentColor())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
    def onCurrentColorChanged(self, color):
        self.setStyleSheet("QColorDialog { background-color: %s}" % color.name())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ColorDialog()
    if w.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
        print(w.currentColor())
```